# Send mail through proxy

Tags: email, nginx, proxy, smtp

I would like to set up a proxy for SMTP traffic by this i mean send and receive mail through a proxy.

I have a machine which is not directly connect to an internet gateaway, I already have an squid proxy for http and https but now i need to send mail (receive is not fundamental)

Which tools do you advice me to use and if you have some doc or tutorial to use this tool as an smtp proxy it would be great. (I'm running on CentOS 7)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: For now nothing, maybe this : https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/mail-proxy/ but there are some parts i don't understand

Comment: I found out that our proxy server intercepting that protocol. so i suggest get smtp credentials on your administrator.

Comment: i'm using squid today as proxy, so you are telling me to put in squid my smtp credentials ? Sorry i'm a begginner i need more details ^^